# Societal issues stemming from having two sentient species that can interbreed generating infertile offspring

Tags: society, modern-age, races

Premise:

Both races are humanoid, covered with fur, similar in intelligence, dexterity etc... Evolved in parallel to fill very similar environments, and split off the other (genetically) relatively recently.

Due to having very different cultures(think medieval Chinese and Britons) and the fact that the races were on separate continents, interbreeding wasnt a big issue, especially given the fact, that

Interbreeding causes the offspring to be infertile. Think donkeys and horses. Mules are bigger, stronger and more docile but infertile. And less interested in sex overall. Similar effects here. Intelligence, dexterity and agility is not affected however and varies with the normal distribution. There would be precedents of course like within slavery etc... but nothing world-threatening.

Think two tall(6') mixed parents could have a 7'6 child.

For the sake of mental imagery lets call them cat-people, dog-people and mule-people.

Now it's 21st century, and like in our world, societal barriers are breaking down. Cat-people and dog-people serve similar roles in the global society, They're all in a mix everywhere, cohabit easily, cat and dog children go to the same schools and one might have had a white collar job boss that was the opposite race. Think metropolitan, white and blue collar societies.

How would mule-people integrate?

How plausible is it for mules to be welcomed like just-another-person? How plausible is it for them to be shunned?

Inability to have offspring kind of dooms the mule societies from ever being large in numbers. How would that affect the mule-nonmule relations?

Would low libido cause mules to be uninterested in having offspring, or rather would be more determined to be parents?

Any real life analogies?
(Thanks, Bald Bear}

EDIT:
@Frostfyre and @Alexander:
The "background" is modern todays world. Assuming we are two "human-like" races which get along like we do now (say like asians and europeans do), how would existence of mules affect their relationships, also, I asked specifically about:

- integration,
- shunning,
- minority status
- offspring

All of those are closely related and focus on the acceptance/non-acceptance of a particular (species?) in the culture.

@L.Dutch
For the same reason people who by no choice of their own can't have offspring. Or whey wouldn't because it's not in their brains. I don't know, so I'm asking so that I may have a chance of getting feedback from someone who, for example had an experience with asexual people(unsure if the term applies tho).
^ What I mean here, if they can't have their own offspring, would they try to have "offspring" in other ways.

Comment: This is... incredibly broad. There are so many different cultures in a world that answering how "society" changes in response to a certain stimulus would require a library's worth of books.

Comment: If they know they are infertile, why would they bother having offspring?

Comment: "two tall(6') mixed parents could have a 7'6 child" - so dog-people and cat-people are similar in size, but mule-people are physically superior? I presume that your world will have a rich history or racial tensions and relations, and it's necessary to make an idea of this history (which can be part of an answer) before moving to XXI century.

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific than "they get along like Asians and Europeans do". Asia comprises something like half the world's population, has many different ethnic groups (Muslims, Hindus, Sikhs, the Japanese), and even within those ethnic groups there are differing opinions towards the west.

Comment: @F1Krazy Exactly. and in this very diverse world, would being infertile and crossbred even matter? I accept that in non-cosmopolitan situations you can have *anything* but I'm thinking more in Amsterdam, Tokyo or New York scope.

Comment: First off, placing @-mentions in a post body doesn't notify a user. Second, to address your commentary: The problem is that society is _huge_. One group of people will respond very differently to a stimulus than another group based on historical, religious, political, and economical justifications (among others). Also, your last question, "Did I miss anything?" is a red flag that a question is _too broad_ or _primarily opinion-based_.

Comment: immediate RL analogy are homosexual and transgender people: they cannot breed (not with their chosen sex), they are hates by some, and accepted by others. Some societies allow them to live normally and adopt children, some societies sentence them to death.

Comment: one difference with my analogy to homosexuals is that your mule cannot pretend to be a "conventional" person. But on the other side, physical strength of mules would be a great benefit to society that lets them strive and contribute to said society.

Comment: And finally, we can go beyond real world, and imagine that the rich/noble of both primary races take concubines from the poor of other races, and use the resulting mules for manual labor or military purposes. In social sciences, all sort of weird stuff is possible.

Comment: Nice way to frame the situation.
I've edited the question to become less "broad", hopefully You'll be able to post this as an answer :)